# Monte Carlo computational cost

Tags: monte-carlo, optimization

[image: Paper]

Hello. I'm reading the above paper and I do not understand how they managed to solve eq (17.35) -- i've seen many papers skip through this as trivial and didn't bother to show the method to get there.

I would be grateful is someone could explain the steps from get to the solution given.

Many thanks.

HP

Comment: I understand after the minimisation we get n = h^2...but I don't understand what happens next....how can we relate the cost to the MSE?

Comment: Perhaps this is where I am going wrong....does the minimisation of the cost give n = h^2?

Comment: It is a simple two dimensional optimization with one constraint. Write down the Lagrangian and set its derivatives to zero... Sorry, I am too lazy to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

[image: I used Latex to write out the process:]

[image]

Please let me know if you have any questions.